# Error and delay from Youtube Video Downloader made with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, youtube

I can download the video, but it doesn't display the string "Download Completed" and the video doesn't appears in the path I selected, instead it appears in the folder that I saved my code. Also, the console shows me an error and it takes a while to download the video.

The purpose is very simple, you paste a link of a YouTube video and select a local path that you want your video to be downloaded.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from moviepy import *
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from pytube import YouTube
import shutil

screen = Tk()
title = screen.title("Youtube Downloader")
canvas = Canvas(screen, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

def select_path():
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    path_label.config()

def download_video():
    get_link = link_field.get()
    user_path = path_label.cget("text")
    screen.title('Downloading... Please wait...')
    mp4_video = YouTube(get_link).streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
    vid_clip = VideoFileClip(mp4_video)
    vid_clip.close()
    shutil.move(mp4_video, user_path)
    screen.title('Download Completed!')

logoimg = PhotoImage(file="images/download.png")
logoimg = logoimg.subsample(2, 2)
canvas.create_image(250, 80, image=logoimg)

link_field = Entry(screen, width=50)
link_label = Label(screen, text="Paste Download Link: ", font=("Sans Serif", 13))

canvas.create_window(250, 170, window=link_label)
canvas.create_window(250, 210, window=link_field)

path_label = Label(screen, text="Select Local Path: ", font=("Sans Serif", 13))
select_button = Button(screen, text="Select", command=select_path)    # Select Button

canvas.create_window(250, 270, window=path_label)
canvas.create_window(250, 320, window=select_button)

download_bttn = Button(screen, text="Download Video", font=("Sans Serif", 12),  command=download_video)
canvas.create_window(250, 400, window=download_bttn)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you moving the file after downloading it instead of passing in `user_path` inside `.download()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't actually updating your `path_label` text. You call `path_label.config()` in `select_path()`, but you aren't passing anything to the `config` call. I assume you want `path_label.config(text=path)`.

*However* - this is an unorthodox way of handling this sort of thing. You may have an easier time binding a `StringVar()` to your `path_label`'s `textvariable`. That way, whenever the value of the `StringVar()` changes (via a call to `StringVar.set()`), the label is updated automatically. You can also easily retrieve the value with `StringVar.get()`

```
path_var = StringVar("Select Local Path: ")
path_label = Label(screen, textvariable=path_var, font=("Sans Serif", 13))
```

```
def select_path():
    # update the variable bound to path_label
    path_var.set(filedialog.askdirectory())
```

```
# fetch the current value of 'path_var'
user_path = path_var.get()
```

Comment: Using `<Label>.config(text=...)` is more common (and looks cleaner in my opinion) than `<StringVar>.set(...)`.

Comment: @TheLizzard Using labels to store values feels un-pythonic to me, at the very least

Comment: Retrieving the value using a `Label` is unpythonic. Having a variable that is a normal python `str` that holds the path is the best solution imo. To me setting/retrieving the path from a `tk.StringVar` and `tk.Label` are the same, but with one, you have more options on how to change it.

Comment: @TheLizzard A plain-old `str` definitely works, but I assumed OP wanted to be able to see the value via the `Label`. That said: OP, if you aren't worried about *seeing* the path value on your GUI, skip the `Label` and `StringVar` business altogether and use a string like TheLizzard suggests!

Comment: I meant both a normal global python `str`ing variable as well as the `tk.Label`.

Comment: @TheLizzard Ah, I misunderstood! Fair point.